# PHP zip_open() and php://temp, can't seem to open

Tags: php, stream, zip

Not sure if this is possible, but it's become an academic struggle now.

Using the `__halt_compiler()` trick to embed binary data in a PHP file, I've successfully created a self-opening script which will `fseek()` to `__COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__` (*not too hard seeing as this precise example is documented in the manual*)

Anyways, I've stored a small lump of binary ZIP data (*a single folder containing a single file that says "hello world"*) after my call to `__halt_compiler()`

What I've tried to do is copy the data directly to the `php://temp` stream, and have done so with success (*if I `rewind()` and `passthru()` the temporary stream handle, it dumps the data*)

```
$php = fopen(__FILE__, 'rb');
$tmp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+b');
fseek($php, __COMPILER_HALT_OFFSET__);
stream_copy_to_stream($php, $tmp);
```

My problem comes with trying to now open `php://temp`<sup>1</sup> with `zip_open()`

```
$zip = zip_open('php://temp');
```

> <sup>1</sup>From what I can see (*despite other such possibilities as lack of stream support with `zip_open()`*) the problem here is the inherent non-permanence of data in `php://memory` and `php://temp` streams between handles. If this can be worked around, perhaps it is in fact possible.

It keeps kicking back error code `11`, which I have found **no**<sup>2</sup> documentation on (*seemingly, like most other possible error codes*)

```
var_dump($zip); // int(11)
```

> <sup>2</sup> As @cweiske pointed out, error code `11 = ZipArchive::ER_OPEN`, *Can't open file*

Is this consequence to my attempt at using the `php://temp` stream, or some other possible issue? I'm also aware there exists an OOP approach (*`ZipArchive`, et al.*) but I figured I'd start with the basics.

Any ideas?

Comment: Alrighty, so error code **11** is an **error open** according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-open.php#102849 regarding the `ZipArchive` class. I would assume this translates as the class would be a wrapper to the same extension functionality.

Comment: The previously linked comment also makes mention of said error returned on varying Windows OS, when trying to unzip a file stored in `c:\windows\temp` While my attempt used the `php://temp` stream which can dump to a file when the data length exceeds the cap, it wouldn't be there, and I switched to `php://memory` anyways, still resulting in an **error open**.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon - *Edited*; no not writing, only reading actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

11 is the constant `ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OPEN`, which the manual describes with

> Can't open file

Note that the manual does *not* state that stream wrappers may be used.

---

Please think about using PHP's **phar** extension - it does what you want, and is well tested.

Comment: Thanks @cweiske - I'm aware of **phar**, however this was more of an academic investigation, learning more about streams and archive support simultaneously. Without explicit mention that stream wrappers may be used in this context, can we safely assume this is not possible? I guess it sure seems like it. Should I further assume that PHP has little (*read, no*) support for working with ZIP archive binary data from memory, in any fashion? Making use of a temp file for an intermediary dump would be fine practically speaking, but I'm still curious about working strictly in memory.

Comment: I've also discovered that by re-opening the `php://temp` stream, it flushes the existing contents. Whether or not `zip_open()` supports stream wrappers, this would certainly be a problem since I'm effectively passing in an empty buffer, and I can't pass an existing stream resource handle to `zip_open()`