# php://memory & php://temp; preserving stream data on subsequent handle creation

Tags: php, memory, stream, handle, temporary

This question is closely related to my new findings, regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910363/php-zip-open-and-php-temp-cant-seem-to-open).

Is there any way to preserve the in stream data of `php://memory` or `php://temp` between handles? I read (*somewhere I can't source off hand*) that subsequent openings of the aforementioned streams clears existing data.

```
$mem1 = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
fwrite($mem1, 'hello world');
rewind($mem1);
fpassthru($mem1); // "hello world"

$mem2 = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
rewind($mem2);
fpassthru($mem2); // empty
```

So again my question is, is there anyway to force existing data to persist in stream when creating a new handle to it?

(*The latter call to `fpassthru()` would of course dump `hello world` given this is possible*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Opening one of the pseudo-streams `php://temp` or `php://memory` always opens a new stream, what means, that every stream your open this way is unique. So you can't read the content of the stream you have previously written to *another* one.

Comment: Thanks @KingCrunch - I was afraid of that (*albeit expecting it*) This is unfortunate, as I was hoping to pass streams by URI, rather than handle for reasons explained in the linked question. If you care to gander at said question, perhaps you can assist with a solution, or at least further confirm that it's impossible. Thanks again :)

Comment: @TomcatExodus: Usually one creates temporary files for that. If you want to keep the data in memory, there is no benefit against common variables (and such). Don't know, what you are trying, but usually you'll pass one value to a function/method, where the value should be used. You are talking about something similar to globals variables, which are ugly anyway.

Comment: The issue (*if you're referring to the linked question*) is that `zip_open()` requires a valid URI (*scheme doesn't seem to be important, but I'm not that far along*) as opposed to a handle to/variable containing raw binary data. I'm trying to "trick" it into reading the `php://memory` stream, which will contain the raw binary dump of the self contained, compile-halted archive data.

Answer (score 0):

If you need in-memory virtual stream that persists data you can use https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream - although it's mainly used for testing I/O operations it should fulfill your requirements - it stores data within internal objects which are identified by virtual URLs so you can access same data in memory by accessing same URL.

Answer (score 0):

The handlers are unique, so you'll have to pass the handler, or (god forbid) keep the handler global

`$GLOBALS['my_global_memory_stream']=fopen('php://memory','r+');`